# How to dispose Single observer in RxJava2 when used in background and not in Activity/Fragment

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android

How to dispose Single observer  in RxJava2 when used in background and not in Activity/Fragment.

I know if Single used in Activity/Fragment then it can be added in composite disposer and dispose it in Activity/Fragment's onDestroy method.

But how to dispose it when it is called from somewhere else?

Also what are the other ways to dispose Single if it is called from Activity/Fragment and we want to dispose it before onDestroy being called?

Comment: it doesn't matter where you use them. There will be a moment where you don't need them anymore, that is when you dispose of them. *Also what are the other ways to dispose Single if it is called from Activity/Fragment and we want to dispose it before onDestroy being called?* -- dispose them somewhere else?

Comment: Can i dispose in onSuccess and onError method?

Comment: no that would beat the purpose. Dispose is intended to *dispose* of an observable that has not yet completed

Comment: You mean, i do not require to dispose Single after onSuccess being called. Am i Right?

Comment: @TimCastelijns - Single and May be are intended to emit data only once. and after that sream will terminate. So do i require to dispose single nd Maybe after it emits data?

Comment: Where you able to find out whether a `Single` needs to be manually disposed? I'm trying to find an answer to this question too. I see that a `ConsumerSingleObserver` that a `Single` uses internally calls `lazySet(DisposableHelper.DISPOSED)` on success and on error, which makes it look like it disposes it automatically, but I'm wondering if there's something else that I may be missing.

Answer (score 5):

Two of the default observers (`ConsumerSingleObserver` and `BiConsumerSingleObserver`) that are returned by `Single` when you `subscribe` dispose themselves `onError` and `onSuccess`. If you pass in your own custom `SingleObserver`, you need to decide when to dispose it.

> A Single will call only one of these methods, and will only call it once. Upon calling either method, the Single terminates and the subscription to it ends.
>   (http://reactivex.io/documentation/single.html)

In some cases you may want to dispose of the `SingleObserver` before it disposes itself, in which case you just need to call `dispose` on a `Disposable` returned by a `subscribe`. When and where you call it really depends on your particular situation.

If your `Single` doesn't complete before your life-cycled object gets destroyed (e.g. HTTP calls), you must dispose the observer in a destroy callback of the life-cycled object.